# UIPicker in inappsettingskit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, inappsettingskit

Using inappsettingskit, I'm searching for a way to display an uipickerview (with custom values) when clicking on a textfield cell (instead of a keyboard).

Is there any way to do so ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the setting in you application and for showing picker view instead of standard keyboard use `UITextField` **inputView** property.

```
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView;
```

**[From Apple Documentation for inputView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) .**

> If the value in this property is nil,
>   the text field displays the standard
>   system keyboard when it becomes first
>   responder. Assigning a custom view to
>   this property causes that view to be
>   presented instead.